# TypeError: Cannot match against 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

**Code**

```
client.createPet(pet, (err, {name, breed, age}) => {
  if (err) {
    return t.error(err, 'no error')
  }
  t.equal(pet, {name, breed, age}, 'should be equivalent')
})
```

**Error**

```
client.createPet(pet, (err, {name, breed, age}) => {
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot match against 'undefined' or 'null'.
```

Why am I getting this error? My knowledge of ES6 led me to presume that this error should only arise if the *array or object being destructured or its children* is `undefined` or `null`.

I wasn't aware that function parameters are used as a match. And if they are then why is it only an error if I try to destructure one of them? (that isn't `undefined` or `null`).

Answer (score 69, accepted):

> this error should only arise if the array or object being destructured or its children is `undefined` or `null`.

Exactly. In your case, the object being destructured is either `undefined` or `null`. For example,

```
function test(err, {a, b, c}) {
  console.log(err, a, b, c);
}

test(1, {a: 2, b: 3, c: 4});
// 1 2 3 4
test(1, {});
// 1 undefined undefined undefined
test(1);
// TypeError: Cannot match against 'undefined' or 'null'.
```

Comment: You're right, I got misled by the arrow in the error message

Comment: @PrashanthChandra If you look closely, the arrow actually points to the opening parenthesis, not error :-)

Comment: It is a shame that a feature that was just recently released doesn't have a more informative and helpful message

Comment: Dang, I thought I had discovered an elegant solution for null checking by destructuring undefined. Oh well, destructuring `{}` is still pretty handy for handling null values with default function values.

Comment: That makes sense. :D