# How to test a stateless component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to test below component but getting error, its a functional component with some data.

The below component receive list of informations from parent component and renders, its work perfectly, but when writing test cases its failing using jest and enzyme

```
import React from "react";

export const InfoToolTip = data => {
  const { informations = [] } = data.data;

  const listOfInfo = () => {
    return informations.map((info, index) => {
      const { name, id } = info;
      return [
        <li>
          <a
            href={`someURL?viewMode=id`}
          >
            {name}
          </a>
        </li>
      ];
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="tooltip">
        <ul className="desc">{listOfInfo()}</ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Test case**

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow, mount } from "enzyme";
import { InfoToolTip } from "../index.js";

describe("InfoToolTip", () => {
  it("tooltip should render properly",() => {
    const wrapper = mount(<InfoToolTip  />);
  });
});
```

**Error:
TypeError: Cannot match against 'undefined' or 'null'.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you `mount` `InfoToolTip` you don't pass any props while in component you try to destructure `data` prop:

```
const { informations = [] } = data.data;
```

So you could fix it this way:

```
const wrapper = mount(<InfoToolTip data={{}} />);
```

[Related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37453472/4443323)

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, could you help me how to test listOfInfo function, i didnt find any example.

Comment: @Mukesh Checkout [this article.](https://medium.com/backticks-tildes/testing-your-react-component-with-jest-and-enzyme-276eef45bea0) It explains how to test stateless components with Jest and Enzyme.